# автоматический скрол на странице

Tags: javascript

Вот мой код. Он работает нормально только на мозила. Помогите мне пожалуйста. Нужно чтобы работал на всех браузерах. сайт http://aksis.at/agentur/
Если откроете через мозилу то увидите что все хoрашо работает так как должно, но если через другой браузер (например safari) то все не так уж хорошо. Спасибо за помощь.

```
jQuery(function($){
 let div = $j('html, body');
 setInterval(function(){
 let pos = div.scrollTop();
 div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
}, 30)
})
```

Comment: оформите ваш вопрос должным образом, приведите весь код страницы

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: `let div = $j('html, body');` :(

Answer (score 0):

Я обнаружил, что .scrollTop будет работать на $("body") но не $("html, body") , FF и IE, однако работает наоборот. Простое обнаружение браузера устраняет проблему:

```
if($.browser.safari)
    bodyelem = $("body")
else
    bodyelem = $("html,body")

bodyelem.scrollTop(100)
```

Значение браузера jQuery для Chrome - это Safari, поэтому вам нужно только обнаружить это.

Помогите совместить с моим кодом